# DropDownList C# Mvc4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I don't understand how to pass this selectListitem in the controller, how to send that to the view ?
With `return view("MyView", listItems )` ? But it says that `listItems` doesn't exist in the current context ! Have you an idea ? Thanks

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "Exemplo1",
          Value = "Exemplo1"
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Exemplo2",
            Value = "Exemplo2",
            Selected = true
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Exemplo3",
            Value = "Exemplo3"
        });
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tipo, listItems, "-- Select Status --")
```

I precise that there is already a model in my view for a form.  I want to fill one field of the form with the dropdownlist. That's why i whant to use the HtmlHelper `DropDownListFor`.

Comment: add it to your view bag.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial. There's obviously a lot more gaps in your knowledge than can be answered here.

Comment: You're right my question is too vast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to define a model, and pass that model class into the view. Ditch ViewBag and use a strongly typed model.

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public int ddlSelectedValue {get; set;}
  List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> DDLItems { get; set; } //Instantiate this through Constructor    
}


ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

int val = 5;
model.DDLItems.Add( new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text", Value = Val.ToString() });

return view (model)

View
@model NameSpace.ViewModel


@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ddlSelectedValue, Model.DDLItems)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response, it works but i've already a model in my view for my form.

Comment: @Julien, well the ground work is laid out for now, just make the necessary changes to your model to incorporate this logic.

Comment: yes, i agree with you it's logic. I am going to do that !

Answer (score 0):

HERE GO IN THE VIEW
@{

```
List<User> listaUsers = (List<User>)ViewBag.ListUser;
```

}

```
                foreach (User us in listaUsers)
                {

                        <option value="@us.UserID">@us.Name</option>

                }

        </select>


    /// Name function its like name of view for binding this part go to the controller
    public ActionResult anytingName()
    {
        User us= new User();
        us.Name="paul";
        us.UserID=1;
        List<User> users= new List<User>();
        users.Add(us);
        ViewBag.ListUser = users;
        return View();
    }
```